# Connecting to IBM MQ from UFT

Tags: ibm-mq, qtp, hp-uft

I have been trying to read and write messages to MQ from UFT. I am using the dotnet factory instance. i have reached till a point where i am able to connect to MQ while i am facing a problem in accessing the queue and read and write messages.

The code is as follows.

```
strQMgrName = "queue manager name"
strMQMDllPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\WebSphere MQ\\bin\\amqmdnet.dll"
Set oMqEnvironment = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQEnvironment",strMQMDllPath)
oMqEnvironment.Hostname = "host name"
oMqEnvironment.Port = "port number"
oMqEnvironment.Channel = "channel name"


Set oMQC = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQC",strMQMDllPath)
' qmanager name,channel name, connection name
Set oMqQMgr = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager",strMQMDllPath,strQMgrName)
```

oMqQMgr.isConnected ' gives true

Now i wan to use the method

```
public MQQueue AccessQueue(string queueName, int openOptions)
```

of the instance IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager. can someone guide me in doing the same and let me know how i can push messages and read messages from the mentioned queue

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of googling and reading IBM documentation , i was able to put and get messages in MQ from UFT. .. Below in the code snippet that worked for me .. Hope this helps some one .. I was working on PUT and GET separately, hence there might be some repetition in the code.

Prerequisite for this.. You have to download MQ Client from IBM site and install it on PC where UFT is installed.. IBM MQ client is a freeware

```
  Dim oMQEnvironment
    Dim oMQM
    Dim oMQC
    Dim oMQMessage
    Dim oMQQueue
    Dim intOpenOptions


    strMQMDLLPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\WebSphere MQ\\bin\\amqmdnet.dll"
    strHostName= "Host Name"
    intPort = "Port Number"
    strChannel ="Channel Name"
    strMessage ="UFT Test Message"
    strMQManager = "Quemanager Name"
    strMessageQueue = "Queue Name"
```

' This part of the code is blatantly copied from one of the posts online. Will post the link once i find it again

'for application(UFT) to connect to a queue manager in client mode

```
 Set oMQEnvironment = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQEnvironment",strMQMDLLPath)

    'Initize the Environment
    With oMQEnvironment
    .HostName = strHostName 
    .Port = intPort
    .Channel = strChannel 
    End with

    On Error Resume Next
    'Create MQ Instatnces
    Set oMQM = DotnetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager",strMQMDLLPath)

    'Check if MQM Connected
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Reporter.ReportEvent micFail , "Step: Creating MQM Object" , "Unable to Connect to MQ Manager at" & strHostName
        'Exit Test
    End If

    Set oMQC = DotnetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQC",strMQMDLLPath)
    Set oMQMessage = DotnetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQMessage",strMQMDLLPath)

    'Declare Q open options
    intOpenOptions = oMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT or oMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING ' 16 + 8192

    'Open the Q to post the messages
    If strRemoteMQManager = "" Then
    Set oMQQueue = oMQM.AccessQueue(strMessageQueue , intOpenOptions)
    Else 
    Set oMQQueue = oMQM.AccessQueue(strMessageQueue , intOpenOptions ,strRemoteMQManager, "","" )
    End If

    'Format Message
    With oMQMessage
    .CharacterSet = 819
    .WriteString(strMessage)
    End with

    'Post Message
    With oMQQueue
    .Put(oMQMessage)
    .Close()
    End With
```

Now for getting the message from MQ

```
Dim oMQEnvironment
Dim oMQM
Dim oMQC
Dim oMQMessage
Dim oMQQueue

strMQMDLLPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\WebSphere MQ\\bin\\amqmdnet.dll"
strHostName= "host name"
intPort = "port number"
strChannel ="channel name"
strMessage ="UFT Test Message"
strMessageQueue = "message queue intended to access"
strMQManager = "mq manager name"
strRemoteMQManager=""

'Create MQ Instances
Set oMQC = DotnetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQC",strMQMDLLPath)

'set the properties of the Queue manager
Set properties = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("System.Collections.Hashtable")
                properties.Add oMQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, strHostName
                properties.Add oMQC.PORT_PROPERTY, intPort
                properties.Add oMQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, strChannel

'access the queue manager 
Set oMQM = DotnetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQQueueManager",strMQMDLLPath,strMQManager,properties)

'here We are trying to browse the message one by one and keep the messages on the queue.

'Declare Q open options
Set oMQQueue = oMQM.AccessQueue(strMessageQueue,oMQC.MQOO_BROWSE)
Set oMQGetMessageOptions = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQGetMessageOptions",strMQMDLLPath) 
oMQGetMessageOptions.Options = oMQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_FIRST

Set oMQMessage = DotnetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQMessage",strMQMDLLPath)

    oMQQueue.Get oMQMessage,oMQGetMessageOptions

Set mqGetNextMsgOpts = DotNetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQGetMessageOptions",strMQMDLLPath) 
mqGetNextMsgOpts.Options = oMQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT

browseMessages = true

Do while browseMessages
        on error resume next
        messageText = oMQMessage.ReadString(oMQMessage.MessageLength)
        'Print messageText
        Set oMQMessage = DotnetFactory.CreateInstance("IBM.WMQ.MQMessage",strMQMDLLPath)
        oMQQueue.Get oMQMessage,mqGetNextMsgOpts
        if Err.Number <> 0 then browseMessages =false   
        'Clear both MsgID and CorrelID for next use.
        oMQMessage.MessageId = oMQC.MQMI_NONE
        oMQMessage.CorrelationId = oMQC.MQCI_NONE           
Loop 

'Cleanup
Set oMQQueue = Nothing 
Set oMQMessage= Nothing 
Set oMQOpenOptions= Nothing 
Set oMQM= Nothing 
Set oMQEnvironment = Nothing
```